# If $B^{1/2}A=AB^{1/2}$. It is true that $AB=BA$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space. Let $A\in \mathcal{L}(\mathcal{H})$ and let $B\in \mathcal{L}(E)^+$.

> Assume that $B^{1/2}A=AB^{1/2}$. It is true that $AB=BA$?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\def\h{^{1/2}}$

$$ AB=AB\h B\h = (B\h A) B\h= B\h (AB\h)=B\h B\h A=BA\,.$$